# What are all these "Untitled Window" icons in launcher and how do I get rid of them?

Tags: 12.10, launcher

They just showed up this afternoon.

[image: Launcher Icons]

Currently running applications (off the top of my head):

- Chrome
- Skype
- PHPStorm
- Pandora
- XChat
- Terminal
- Dropbox
- Conky
- Vagrant (1 VM running)
- Terminal

I quit all applications and the icons didn't go away. Has anybody else experienced this? Does anybody have at least some pointers for how to figure out what's even going on?

Thanks, any help is much appreciated!

### EDIT

Forgot to mention: each of the launcher icons has a blank menuitem where the program name should be and "unlock from launcher" and "quit" that show up upon right clicking the icon. None of these actually do anything when clicked, though.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but holy mother your desktop is sexy

Comment: Does this problem persists if you logout and log back in? I think the problem may be in some `.desktop` files that are located at `$HOME/.local/share/applications/`, `/usr/local/share/applications/` or `/usr/share/applications/`. Can you `cd` into these 3 and then execute `grep -ir icon .` then we can check if for each "icon=/path/icon" there is really an icon path?

Comment: @jackweirdy haha, thanks! The wallpaper is actually one of the default ones that shipped with quantal. The conky skin is Conky Lua (http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Conky+lua?content=139024)

Comment: @desgua the problem does not persist between login sessions. I'm not actually even sure how to recreate the issue either, so for now, it's "fixed"; I used `grep -ir icon $HOME/.local/share/applications/ /usr/share/applications/ /usr/local/share/applications/ | sed 's/.*Icon=\(.*\)/\1/p;s/.*\.desktop.*//p' | sort | uniq` to get all icon names/paths. Looped through to weed out the absolute paths that actually do exist and got this list: https://gist.github.com/johnpbloch/5387686 How do I check if all of those have icons exist?

Comment: I suspect from some of the Windows programs because Nautilus can't read icons embed in files like 1CD8_rundll32.0 . You can check icons manually, but I will try to make an automated scrip for you ;-)

Comment: Here an automated script http://pastebin.com/qk8Sq2LS (May be you must double check files that ended with .0 )

Answer (score 2):

This icons belong to <strike>sensors</strike> Conky on right side of your desktop.

Comment: You mean Conky?

Comment: Yeah. Try closing it and see what happens.